# Multiple driver-java-options in spark submit

Tags: bash, apache-spark

I am using a spark-submit specified in a bash script as:

```
CLUSTER_OPTIONS=" \
--master yarn-cluster \
--files     file:///${CONF_DIR}/app.conf#app.conf,file:///${CONF_DIR}/log4j-executor.xml#log4j.xml \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.xml" \
--driver-java-options '-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.xml -Dconfig.file=app.conf' \
--keytab ${KEYTAB} \
--principal ${PRINCIPAL} \
"
```

I am finding that app conf is not being picked up as I receive this error:

```
Error: Unrecognized option: -Dconfig.file=file:app.conf'
```

I have also attempted different ways to encapsulate the driver-java-options:

1)

```
--driver-java-options \"-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.xml -Dconfig.file=app.conf\" \

Error: Unrecognized option: -Dconfig.file=file:app.conf"
```

2)

```
--driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.xml -Dconfig.file=file:transformation.conf" \


./start_app.sh: line 30: -Dconfig.file=file:app.conf --keytab /app/conf/keytab/principal.keytab --principal principal : No such file or directory
```

How can i specify multiple *driver-java-options* for use by my Spark app?

N.B. I am using Spark 1.5.0

Comment: can we have rest of your bash scripts if possible?

Comment: could you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 13):

Just writing this because it was so odd. The way I got this to work, it was not until I made --driver-java-options the ***first*** of all arguments. I left it as is so you get the entirety.

Using pyspark
Local mode

```
/opt/apache-spark/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit \
    --driver-java-options "-Xms2G -Doracle.jdbc.Trace=true -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/apache-spark/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/oraclejdbclog.properties -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1098 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.2.120 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1095" \
    --driver-memory $_driver_memory \
    --executor-memory $_executor_memory \
    --total-executor-cores $_total_executor_cores \
    --verbose \
    --jars /opt/apache-spark/jars/log4j-1.2.17.jar main.py \
    --dbprefix $1 \
    --copyfrom $2
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This indeed helped someone today ! Thanks !

Comment: And again it did :)

Comment: And one more time here !

Answer (score 8):

Try to use:

```
 --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.xml -Dconfig.file=app.conf"
```

In my case, it works great along --files as you used it

You may want to add:

```
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=...."
```

if the files are accessed from the executors

Hope it helps,
Regards

Comment: Doesn't work: Error: Unrecognized option: -Dconfig.file=app.conf"

Comment: @nonotb, how does it work in terms of the files process. Is it that the spark-submit tries to upload the files from whereever you run the command. so e.g. i am in client/edge node, and i have folder /abc/def/app.conf   I then use spark_submit --files /abc/def/app.conf     and then what? how does executor access these files? should i also place the file on hdfs/maprfs, and make sure the spark.esecutor.extraJavaOptions=-Dconfig.file=/absolut/path/of/hdfs/maprfs? Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Working 2018 in Spark 2.3.0

```
spark2-submit \
--class com.demo.Main \
--master yarn --deploy-mode client \
--driver-memory 10G --driver-cores 8 --executor-memory 13G --executor-cores 4 \
--num-executors 10 \
--verbose \
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dconfig.file=/$HOME/application.conf -Dlog4j.configuration=$HOME/log4j.properties" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dconfig.file=$HOME/application.conf -Dlog4j.configuration=$HOME/log4j.properties" \
--files "application.conf,log4j.properties" \
$HOME/ingestion-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

On Spark 2.4.5, further complicated by Docker and env var passing through to an in-container `spark-submit` wrapper:

```
SPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--conf spark.driver.host=host.docker.internal --conf spark.driver.port=46111"
```

The spark-submit wrapper container then executed like so:

```
docker run \
    -e SPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="${SPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS}" \
    $IMAGE_NAME
```

where `SPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` env var is referenced by the `spark-submit` wrapper script.

Sample run output, with configuration being dumped out by the driver code:

```
20/09/15 08:02:13 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.4.5
20/09/15 08:02:13 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: rule-query-app
20/09/15 08:02:13 INFO SparkContext: Spark configuration:
spark.app.name=rule-query-app
spark.driver.host=host.docker.internal
spark.driver.port=46111
spark.jars=file:/app/rule-query-spark-app-fat.jar
spark.logConf=true
spark.master=spark://host.docker.internal:7077
spark.submit.deployMode=client
```

Kudos to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44131334/3996058) (upvoted, too!) providing the `--conf` hint.